# Pull and post data from MySQL using dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, mysql, menu, dropdown

I'm a complete newbie in php & MySQL 
Basically what I want to do is be able to retrieve data from a table 
in MySQL database and put it in a drop down menu . 
After I fill in the other fields I want to data from the drop down menu to be written to another table in the same database .

This is my insert.php file

```
        <?php

        #### INSERTS A SINGLE CUSTOMER IN Company-->Customer Database with UTF8 Change for special German Characters  - Cyrilic Doesnt work - Other change then utf8 ???
        #### Getting Data from Index.php 


        $servername = "127.0.0.1";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "company";    

        //making an array with the data recieved, to use as named placeholders for INSERT by PDO.


        #### Getting DAta from Index.php 
        $data = array('CustomerName' => $_POST['CustomerName'] , 'Address1' => $_POST['Address1'], 'Address2' => $_POST['Address2'], 'City' => $_POST['City'], 'PostCode' => $_POST['PostCode'], 'CountryID' => $_POST['CountryID'], 'ContactName' => $_POST['ContactName'], 'ContactEmail' => $_POST['ContactEmail'], 'ContactPhone' => $_POST['ContactPhone'], 'ContactFax' => $_POST['ContactFax'], 'Website' => $_POST['Website']);

        try {
            // preparing database handle $dbh
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")); ### Database Connect with Special characters Change 
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            // query with named placeholders to avoid sql injections
            $query = "INSERT INTO customer (CustomerName, Address1, Address2, City, PostCode, CountryID, ContactName, ContactEmail, ContactPhone, ContactFax, Website ) 
            VALUES (:CustomerName, :Address1, :Address2, :City, :PostCode, :CountryID, :ContactName, :ContactEmail, :ContactPhone, :ContactFax, :Website )";
            //statement handle $sth
            $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
            $sth->execute($data);
            echo "New record created successfully";
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
        $dbh = null;
        ?>
```

And this is the source from the html page

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Add New Product</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="CustomerName">CustomerName:</label>
                <input type="text" name="CustomerName" id="CustomerName">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Address1">Address 1:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Address1" id="Address1">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="Address2">Address 2:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Address2" id="Address2">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="City">City:</label>
                <input type="text" name="City" id="City">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="PostCode">Post Code:</label>
                <input type="text" name="PostCode" id="PostCode">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="CountryID">Country ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="CountryID" id="CountryID">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="ContactName">Contact Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ContactName" id="ContactName">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="ContactEmail">Contact Email:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="ContactPhone">Contact Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ContactPhone" id="ContactPhone">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="ContactFax">Contact Fax:</label>
                <input type="text" name="ContactFax" id="ContactFax">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="Website">Website:</label>
                <input type="text" name="Website" id="Website">
            </p>

            <input type="submit" value="Add Records">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

So I wanna add this php code that pulls out the country list and prefixes for the phone numbers and then when I hit the submit button the actual output of the drop down menu to we written in the customers table

```
                <p>
                    <label for="CountryID">Country:</label>

                        <?php
                        $servername = "localhost";
                        $username = "root";
                        $password ="";
                        $dbname = "company";

                        $con_qnt = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);      
                        if(!mysqli_connect("localhost","root",""))
                        {
                            die('oops connection problem ! --> '.mysqli_connect_error());
                        }
                        if(!mysqli_select_db($con_qnt, "company"))
                        {
                            die('oops database selection problem ! --> '.mysqli_connect_error());
                        }


                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
                        $result = mysqli_query($con_qnt, "SELECT * FROM country" );


                        echo "<select name='label'>";
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo "<option value='" . $row['CountryName' ] . "'>" . $row['CountryName' ] . "     ("  .$row['PhonePrefix' ] . ")"  . "</option>";

                            } 
                        echo "</select>";
                        ?>          
                    <name="CountryID" id="CountryID">
                </p>
```

I don't even know if this is doable - I searched for long time but couldn't find anything that is kind of what I need . Mostly I found hard coded html dropdown menus . In fact hard coding this will work for the countries but it wont work if I want it to be able to show lets say products in a drop down menu . Thank you all in advance .

Comment: So this is what you tried, but what does it do? what errors do you get? Also, try to stick with a single database connector style, I see you are using both mysqli and PDO. You only need one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for the comment . It was putting everything else but the item in the database . No errors . I will rewrite so its all in one connector style .

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just made a quick sample to answer your question on how to populate dropdown using data from database.
In this example, I used

> JQuery's AJAX Function

so first, for the backend, (this is just a quick sample to select data. Do not use this as a pattern for your future codes

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbhelp", 'root', 'pup');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from t_country");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

I repeat. This is just for quick reference. Do not use it as a pattern for your code.
So using that code, we have now selected data from our table country and used`json_encode` to make it in json format. read more about this here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php.

Next one is the frontend(HTML part)

```
<body>
     // empty dropdown button to be filled by data from database
     <select id="country">
     </select>
     //include the jquery library

     <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax ({
                url : 'dropdown_database.php', // the url from which the data will be pulled
                success: function(data) {
                     var country = $.parseJSON(data); // parse the json format data
                     $.each(country, function(i, d) {
                          $('#country').prepend('<option>'+ d.country +'</option>'); // this one adds the <option></option> tag in the dropdown
                     });
                }
          });
     });
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to replace this:

```
<p>
   <label for="CountryID">Country ID:</label>
   <input type="text" name="CountryID" id="CountryID">
</p>
```

With a dropdown so you can quickly pick the country from the dropdown instead of memorizing the ID for each individual country. And to create the `select` you are using this code:

```
<p>
    <label for="CountryID">Country:</label>

    <?php

        // some code here that I removed to avoid noise

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
        $result = mysqli_query($con_qnt, "SELECT * FROM country" );

        echo "<select name='label'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
           echo "<option value='" . $row['CountryName' ] . "'>" . $row['CountryName' ] . "     ("  .$row['PhonePrefix' ] . ")"  . "</option>";
        } 
        echo "</select>";
    ?>

    <name="CountryID" id="CountryID">
</p>
```

That should work fine... after you fix some issues:

1. If you want to replace the `input` with the `select`, the `select` should have the same name as the `input` so the value is processed automatically. Right now the `select` has "label" as the name and there is a strange (and incorrect) `name` tag. To fix this:

   - Get rid of the unnecessary `name` tag.
   - Replace the `name` attribute in the `select` with value "CountryID":

     ```
     echo "<select name='CountryID'>";
     ```
2. The `option` value should be the country ID so, unless the ID is the country name (not the best choice), you are not using the right value. Change that line too:

   ```
   echo "<option value='" . $row['CountryID' ] . "'>" . $row['CountryName' ] . " (" .$row['PhonePrefix' ] . ")" . "</option>";
   ```

   (Considering CountryID as the ID, replace it for the right column name).

And I think with those two changes, the rest of the code should work just fine with insert.php that wouldn't require any updates at all. Finally it would look something like this:

```
<p>
    <label for="CountryID">Country:</label>

    <?php

        // some code here that I removed to avoid noise

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM country";
        $result = mysqli_query($con_qnt, "SELECT * FROM country" );

        echo "<select name='CountryID'>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
           echo "<option value='" . $row['CountryID' ] . "'>" . $row['CountryName' ] . "     ("  .$row['PhonePrefix' ] . ")"  . "</option>";
        } 
        echo "</select>";
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Your Example worked perfectly. And I realized where my mistakes are .  Thank you so much !